# Does the Treaty of Najran have any modern-day applicability?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, history, christianity

This question is related to the paper: *The Prophet’s Treaty with the Christians of Najran: An Analytical Study to Determine the Authenticity of the Covenants*, [Ahmed El-Wakil](http://qfis-qa.academia.edu/AhmedElWakil), Journal of Islamic Studies (2016) 27 (3): 273-354. ([DOI link](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/jis/etw027))  The author writes: "In this paper, source-critical methods are applied to argue that these documents are indeed authentic and can be traced back to the Prophet."

The Treaty of Najran contains a broad range of conditions, one of which is summarized as (referencing [Al-Islam](https://www.al-islam.org/restatement-history-islam-and-muslims-sayyid-ali-ashgar-razwy/expedition-tabuk)):

> No Christian would ever be forced by the Muslims to become a convert to Islam.

**Question**: Does the Treaty of Najran have any modern-day applicability?

It may be that: (a) the Treaty of Najran is widely considered fabricated (or dubious), like other treaties at the time, and therefore does not have modern-day relevance, or (b) the Treaty of Najran was only applicable at the time of the Prophet.  (Or maybe something else entirely is true.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treaties are with political entities and not religions as a whole. Among the Christians: While there was a treaty with the tribes of Najran there was a simultaneous a war with the Byzantines. So the treaty did not apply to *all* Christians *automatically*, it only applied to those who were covered by it and for as long as it was not voided.

The treaty of Najran does have modern day applicability in the sense that within an Islamic state the *Dhimmis* are to be governed by similar treaties with similar provisions and the treaty of Najran is among the sources from which the legality of those provisions are derived. A Dhimmi is a non-Muslim citizen of an Islamic state who became so either by voluntarily agreeing to the treaty, or by being defeated and conquered if the caliph decides to make the prisoners into Dhimmis, or by being the descendant of another Dhimmi with a valid treaty.

The major provisions of the treaty of Najran included:

- Payment of Jizyah i.e. annual tribute to the Muslims by the Christians.  The people of Najran were bound to pay [two thousand garments annually](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3041).

  Jizyah also applies to all other Dhimmis as it is commanded in the Quran:

  > قاتلوا ... حتى يعطوا الجزية
  >
  > Fight ... until they give the jizyah
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 9:29](https://quran.com/9/29?translations=20)</sup>

  And Ahadith:

  > فأمرنا نبينا رسول ربنا صلى الله عليه وسلم أن نقاتلكم حتى تعبدوا الله وحده أو تؤدوا الجزية
  >
  > Our Prophet, the Messenger of our Lord, has ordered us to fight you till you worship Allah Alone or give Jizyah
  >
  > <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3159)</sup>

  > وإذا لقيت عدوك من المشركين فادعهم إلى ثلاث خصال أو خلال فأيتهن ما أجابوك فاقبل منهم وكف عنهم ثم ادعهم إلى الإسلام ... فإن هم أبوا فسلهم الجزية فإن هم أجابوك فاقبل منهم وكف عنهم
  >
  > When you meet your enemies who are polytheists, invite them to three courses of action. If they respond to any one of these, you also accept it and withhold yourself from doing them any harm. Invite them to (accept) Islam; ... If they refuse to accept Islam, demand from them the Jizya. If they agree to pay, accept it from them and hold off your hands.
  >
  > <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/32/3)</sup>

  As for the amount then the madhabs have different conditions regulating it, but in general it depends on what is mutually agreed on in the treaty on a case by case basis. It also depends on whether the people came to be Dhimmis by surrender or by military conquest. The Christians of Najran surrendered without fighting and the amount that was agreed for them was two thousand garments. On the other hand what was agreed for the Jews and Christians of [Yemen](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3038) was for payment of a gold dinar or its equivalent for every adult male every year.
- Right to remain non-Muslims and to not be forced to accept Islam. This also applies to all Dhimmis. This is apparent from the texts mentioned above since they tell to cease fighting after the person agrees to Jizyah and do not say to force him to accept Islam. It is also apparent from the verse:

  > لا إكراه في الدين
  >
  > There shall be no compulsion in [acceptance of] the religion.
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 2:256](https://quran.com/2/256?translations=20)</sup>

  As scholars who hold that this verse is applicable say that it applies specifically to the Dhimmis.
- Subjugation to Islamic laws, for example the people of Najran were not allowed to partake in [interest](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3041).  This applies to all Dhimmis with certain exceptions such as the private consumption of wine or swine, and certain marriage laws (on which there is difference among the madhabs). This is evident from the Quran:

  > أن احكم بينهم بما أنزل الله ولا تتبع أهواءهم واحذرهم أن يفتنوك عن بعض ما أنزل الله إليك
  >
  > And judge between them by what Allah has revealed and do not follow their inclinations and beware of them, lest they tempt you away from some of what Allah has revealed to you.
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 5:49](http://legacy.quran.com/5/49)</sup>

  > قاتلوا الذين لا يؤمنون ... حتى يعطوا الجزية عن يد وهم صاغرون
  >
  > Fight those who do not believe ... until they pay jizyah with their own hands while they are subdued
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 9:29](https://quran.com/9/29?translations=84)</sup>
  >
  > الصغار هو جريان أحكام الإسلام عليهم
  >
  > Being subdued means the imposition of the laws of Islam upon them
  >
  > <sup>— [Tafsir al-Baghawy](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/baghawy/sura9-aya29.html#baghawy)</sup>
- Protection of Churches. This also applies to all other Dhimmis and follows from the permission to retain their religion. However it applies to those churches which are already present at the time of the treaty. Also it applies to those places which are conquered by surrender rather than by military conquest. See [What is the ruling on non-Muslims having Temples, Churches and Synagogues in Muslim lands?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34945/) and [Does Hagia Sophia belong to Muslims?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/61751/).
- Protection of life and property. This also applies to all other Dhimmis. It is evident from the above texts about ceasing fighting after they pay Jizyah. And it is also evident from other texts such as:

  > من قتل معاهدا لم يرح رائحة الجنة، وإن ريحها توجد من مسيرة أربعين عاما
  >
  > Whoever killed a person having a treaty with the Muslims, shall not smell the smell of Paradise though its smell is perceived from a distance of forty years.
  >
  > <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3166)</sup>

  > ألا من ظلم معاهدا أو انتقصه أو كلفه فوق طاقته أو أخذ منه شيئا بغير طيب نفس فأنا حجيجه يوم القيامة
  >
  > If anyone wrongs a Mu'ahid, detracts from his rights, burdens him with
  > more work than he is able to do, or takes something from him without
  > his consent, I will plead for him (the Mu'ahid) on the Day of
  > Resurrection.
  >
  > <sup>— [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3052)</sup>

  > عن عمر ـ رضى الله عنه ـ قال وأوصيه بذمة الله وذمة رسوله صلى الله عليه وسلم أن يوفى لهم بعهدهم، وأن يقاتل من ورائهم، ولا يكلفوا إلا طاقتهم
  >
  > Umar instructed (his would-be-successor) saying, "I urge him (i.e. the new Caliph) to take care of those non-Muslims who are under the protection of Allah and His Apostle in that he should observe the convention agreed upon with them, and fight on their behalf (to secure their safety) and he should not over-tax them beyond their capability.
  >
  > <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3052)</sup>
- Cancellation of the treaty on violations of the treaty from their side. This also applies to other Dhimmis, although there is disagreement on what actions count as voiding the treaty. The evidence is that fighting ceased because of the treaty and so it would begin anew when the treaty is discarded.

For reference you can refer to any work of jurisprudence where it covers the laws of the Ahl al-Dhimma. For example see [Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah  volume  7, page 120-139](https://archive.org/details/FPmfkmfk/mfk07/page/n119/mode/2up?view=theater).

Answer (score -1):

A treaty is not a Covenant, Covenant: A covenant is a solemn promise or commitment in the present of Alaha, typically found in legal documents such as deeds, wills, or agreements. Covenants often involve obligations that run with citizen, land or property, and they are enforceable by law. Unlike contracts, covenants are often perpetual and bind future property owners.

Contract: A contract is a legally binding agreement between two or more parties that outlines the terms, conditions, rights, and obligations of the parties involved. Contracts can encompass various types of agreements, including business contracts, employment agreements, and lease agreements. Our beloved prophet Mohamad clearly stated that the Covenant will be enforce until the end of times. No man Muslim of non-Muslim can violate a covenant that was done by the Prophet himself and Alaha as witness. Just go to Türkiye and see the original text. The reason for which the Christians have been found worthy of this covenant of protection from Allah, His Messenger, and the Believers, is because it is a right they have earned, to which every Muslim is bound, to obtain this covenant established in their favor by the men of this Religion, and which obliges every Muslim to respect it, to defend it, to conserve it, to protect it perpetually, and to live up to it. Like always men want to change what Alaha commands when do not serve their narrative, even in violation of our beloved prophet Mohamad witch and promise.