# Hadith forbidding the killing of Monks

Tags: hadith, sunnah, reference-request

I am looking for the Hadith reference with the following words

> "Do not kill monks in monasteries and do not kill those sitting in places of worship" ( Musnad Ahmad)

Comment: Just in case you didn't notice Musnad Ahmad is a reference, so what exactly do you want? Here some related posts https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/how-should-muslims-treat-houses-of-worship-of-other-religions and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/34945/ruling-on-non-muslims-building-or-having-temples-churches-and-synagogues-in-mus

Comment: @Medi1Saif   Maybe they want authenticity or narration of the hadith or where exactly the hadith is in Musnad Ahmad.

Comment: It is possibly also a saying or order of abu Bakr not of the Prophet pbuh himself, as I've heard similar orders from both.

Answer (score 3):

I could find this as a part of an order of abu Bakr to Yazid ibn abi Sufyan in sunan al-Bayhaqi al-Kubra [كتاب السنن الكبرى](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=71&ID=17591):
In a chapter entitled:

> باب ترك قتل من لا قتال فيه من الرهبان والكبير وغيرهما

Which I would translate as:

> Chapter on refraining from killing monks and old men and others
>
> أن أبا بكر - رضي الله عنه - بعث يزيد بن أبي سفيان إلى الشام فمشى معه يشيعه ، قال يزيد : إني أكره أن تكون ماشيا وأنا راكب ، قال : فقال : إنك خرجت غازيا في سبيل الله ، وإني أحتسب في مشيي هذا معك ، ثم أوصاه فقال : **لا تقتلوا** صبيا ، ولا امرأة ولا شيخا كبيرا ، ولا مريضا ، **ولا راهبا** ، ولا تقطعوا مثمرا ، ولا تخربوا عامرا ، ولا تذبحوا بعيرا ولا بقرة إلا لمأكل ، ولا تغرقوا نحلا ولا تحرقوه . ( وقد روي في ذلك ) عن النبي - صلى الله عليه وسلم .

The bold parts say:

> "Don't kill, ..., (a) monk(s)"

al Bayhaqi added that there are also narrations from the Prophet in this context.

And there's an other narration in [sunan al-Bayhaqi al-Kubra](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?bk_no=71&ID=3772&idfrom=17587&idto=17599&bookid=71&startno=2) on the same circumstances:

> لما بعث أبو بكر - رضي الله عنه - يزيد بن أبي سفيان إلى الشام على ربع من الأرباع ، خرج أبو بكر - رضي الله عنه - معه يوصيه ويزيد راكب ، وأبو بكر يمشي ، فقال يزيد : يا خليفة رسول الله - صلى الله عليه وسلم - إما أن تركب وإما أن أنزل ، فقال : ما أنت بنازل وما أنا براكب ؛ إني أحتسب خطاي هذه في سبيل الله ، يا يزيد ، إنكم ستقدمون بلادا تؤتون فيها بأصناف من الطعام ؛ فسموا الله على أولها ، واحمدوه على آخرها . **وإنكم ستجدون أقواما قد حبسوا أنفسهم في هذه الصوامع ؛ فاتركوهم وما حبسوا له أنفسهم** . وستجدون أقواما قد اتخذ الشيطان على رءوسهم مقاعد : يعني الشمامسة ؛ فاضربوا تلك الأعناق . ولا تقتلوا كبيرا هرما ، ولا امرأة ، ولا وليدا ، ولا تخربوا عمرانا ، ولا تقطعوا شجرة إلا لنفع ، ولا تعقرن بهيمة إلا لنفع ، ولا تحرقن نحلا ولا تغرقنه ، ولا تغدر ، ولا تمثل ، ولا تجبن ، ولا تغلل ، ولينصرن الله من ينصره ورسله بالغيب إن الله قوي عزيز ، أستودعك الله ، وأقرئك السلام - ثم انصرف .

The Bold text means:

> "... and you may find people who have shut themselves away in Synangogs (houses of worship etc.), leave them (don't touch them) for what they shut themselves away for (meaning worship)"

And there's also a hadith of the Prophet () on the authority of ibn 'Abbas and other -in as-[sunan al-Kubra](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?bk_no=71&ID=3772&idfrom=17587&idto=17599&bookid=71&startno=6) of imam al-Bayhaqi- saying:

> إنه كان إذا بعث جيوشه قال : " اخرجوا باسم الله ، تقاتلون في سبيل الله من كفر بالله ، لا تغدروا ، ولا تمثلوا ، ولا تغلوا ، **ولا تقتلوا** الولدان **ولا أصحاب الصوامع** "

The bold part can be translated as:

> "Don't kill ... the people in houses of worship"

A similar narration indeed is present in [Musnad al-Imam Ahmad](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=6&bookhad=2723) (on the authority of ibn 'Abbas ابن عباس) here with the full chain:

> حدثنا **أبو القاسم بن أبي الزناد** قال أخبرني **ابن أبي حبيبة** عن **داود بن الحصين** عن **عكرمة** عن **ابن عباس** قال كان **رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم**
> إذا بعث جيوشه قال اخرجوا بسم الله تقاتلون في سبيل الله من كفر بالله لا تغدروا ولا تغلوا ولا تمثلوا **ولا تقتلوا** الولدان **ولا أصحاب الصوامع**

You may find it in the Musnad in the cahpter entiteled "Musnad bani Hashim", section called "Musnad Abdullah ibn 'Abbas ibn 'abd al-Muttalib from the Prophet ()"

You may find more similar narrations in as-Sunan al-Kubar but with weaker narrator chains and other weaknesses.

Similar ahadith without explictly quoting monks or houses of worship can be found in most other sunni hadith collections (see for example in [al-Muwatta'](https://sunnah.com/urn/509720)).